# Why ScrollView content's position can't be set correctly in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to set ScrollView content's position from the script.
My ScrollView content has Image and the image display inside is changed when a button is pressed.

The image size is different. So I need to change the content's height accordingly.

When I change the height, the content's position is changed.

What I do is when the button is pressed, content's position is recorded as

```
OriginalTransform.transform.position = ScrollViewContent.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchoredPosition;
```

Before the image is loaded, the content's size and position is reset as

```
ScrollViewContent.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchoredPosition = OriginalTransform.transform.position;           
ScrollViewContent.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta = new Vector2(CanvasWidth, 4000);
```

ScrollViewContent.GetComponent ().anchoredPosition is recorded as (0,0,0).

`But when anchoredPosition is reset with  OriginalTransform.transform.position`, content's right value is -750 as shown in the image.

[image]

Why it can't be reposition to its original place?